# Calculate the minimum difference between multiple dates

Tags: r

Dear Stackflow Community,

My dataset consists of  Patient ID and Dates where a specific laboratory value was above the threshold.
**Now I would like to know how to get the minimum difference of all those dates per patient.**
My goal is, to identify patients, with two or more dates which should be in a 2-year window. 
According to my research plan, I would like to calculate a column to state if the minimum difference is not more than two years.

My dataset looks now similar to this:

```
    Patient_ID  Date1   Date2   Date3   Date4   Date5   Date6   Date7   Date8   Date9   Date10  Date11  Date12  Date13  Date14
1   1   13.05.19    13.09.07    13.05.09    13.01.11    13.09.12    13.05.14    13.01.16    13.09.17    14.09.17    15.09.17    16.09.17    17.09.17    18.09.17    19.09.17
2   2   13.07.18    13.11.06    13.07.08    13.03.10    13.11.11    13.07.13    13.03.15    13.11.16    13.09.07    13.07.98    13.05.89    13.03.80    13.01.71    13.11.61
3   3   13.09.17    13.01.06    13.09.07    13.05.09    13.01.11    13.09.12    13.05.14    13.01.16    13.11.06    13.09.97    13.07.88    13.05.79    13.03.70    13.01.61
4   4   13.11.16    13.03.05    13.11.06    13.07.08    13.03.10    13.11.11    13.07.13    13.03.15    13.01.06    13.11.96    13.09.87    13.07.78    13.05.69    13.03.60
5   5   13.01.16    13.05.04    13.01.06    13.09.07    13.05.09    13.01.11    13.09.12    13.05.14    13.03.05    13.01.96    13.11.86    13.09.77    13.07.68    
6   6   13.03.15    13.07.03    13.03.05    13.11.06    13.07.08    13.03.10    13.11.11    13.09.07    13.05.04    13.01.01    13.09.97    13.05.94    13.01.91    
7   7   13.05.14    13.09.02    13.05.04    13.01.06    13.09.07    13.05.09    13.01.11    13.11.06    13.07.03                    
8   8   13.07.13    13.11.01    13.07.03    13.03.05    13.11.06    13.07.08    13.03.10    13.01.06    13.09.02                    
9   9   13.09.12    13.01.01    13.09.02    13.09.07    13.09.12    13.09.17    13.09.22    13.03.05    13.11.01                    
10  10  13.11.11    13.03.00    13.11.01    13.11.06    13.11.11    13.11.16    13.11.21    13.05.04    13.01.01                    
11  11  13.01.11    13.05.99    13.01.01    13.01.06    13.01.11    13.01.16    13.01.21    13.07.03    13.03.00                    
12  12  13.03.10    13.07.98    13.03.00    13.03.05    13.03.10    13.03.15    13.05.19    13.09.02    13.05.99                    
13  13  13.05.09    13.09.97    13.05.99    13.05.04    13.09.07    13.05.14    13.07.18    13.11.01                        
14  14  13.07.08    13.11.96    14.05.99    13.07.03    13.11.06    13.07.13    13.09.17    13.01.01                        
15  15  13.09.07    13.01.96    15.05.99    13.09.02    13.01.06    13.09.12    13.11.16    13.03.00                        
16  16  13.11.06    13.03.95    16.05.99    13.11.01    13.03.05    13.11.11    13.01.16    13.05.99                        
17  17  13.01.06    13.05.94    17.05.99    13.01.01    13.05.04    13.01.11    13.03.15                            
18  18  13.03.05    13.07.93    18.05.99    13.03.00    13.07.03    13.03.10    13.05.14                            
19  19  13.05.04    13.09.92    19.05.99    13.05.99    13.09.02    13.05.09    13.07.13                            
20  20  13.07.03    13.11.91    20.05.99    14.05.99    13.11.01    13.07.08    13.09.12                            
21  21  13.09.02    13.01.91    21.05.99    15.05.99    13.01.01    13.09.07    13.11.11                            
22  22  13.11.01    13.03.90    22.05.99    16.05.99    13.03.00    13.11.06    13.01.11                            
23  23  13.01.01    13.05.89    23.05.99    17.05.99    13.05.99    13.01.06    13.03.10                            
24  24  13.03.00    13.07.88    24.05.99    18.05.99    14.05.99    13.03.05                                
25  25  13.05.99    13.09.87    25.05.99    19.05.99
```

Best wishes and thank you very much for your help,
Caro

Here is the code to access the small data set at the top.

```
structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), Patient_ID = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), Date1 = structure(c(1557705600, 1531440000, 
1505260800, 1478995200, 1452643200, 1426204800, 1399939200, 1373673600, 
1347494400, 1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, 1242172800, 1215907200, 
1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 
1031875200, 1005609600, 979344000, 952905600, 926553600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date2 = structure(c(1189641600, 1163376000, 
1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 1031875200, 1005609600, 
979344000, 952905600, 926553600, 900288000, 874108800, 847843200, 
821491200, 795052800, 768787200, 742521600, 716342400, 689990400, 
663724800, 637286400, 611020800, 584755200, 558489600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date3 = structure(c(1242172800, 1215907200, 
1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 
1031875200, 1005609600, 979344000, 952905600, 926553600, 926640000, 
926726400, 926812800, 926899200, 926985600, 927072000, 927158400, 
927244800, 927331200, 927417600, 927504000, 927590400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date4 = structure(c(1294876800, 1268438400, 
1242172800, 1215907200, 1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, 
1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 
1031875200, 1005609600, 979344000, 952905600, 926553600, 926640000, 
926726400, 926812800, 926899200, 926985600, 927072000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date5 = structure(c(1347494400, 1321142400, 
1294876800, 1268438400, 1242172800, 1215907200, 1189641600, 1163376000, 
1347494400, 1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, 1189641600, 1163376000, 
1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 1031875200, 1005609600, 
979344000, 952905600, 926553600, 926640000, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date6 = structure(c(1399939200, 1373673600, 
1347494400, 1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, 1242172800, 1215907200, 
1505260800, 1478995200, 1452643200, 1426204800, 1399939200, 1373673600, 
1347494400, 1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, 1242172800, 1215907200, 
1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date7 = structure(c(1452643200, 1426204800, 
1399939200, 1373673600, 1347494400, 1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, 
1663027200, 1636761600, 1610496000, 1557705600, 1531440000, 1505260800, 
1478995200, 1452643200, 1426204800, 1399939200, 1373673600, 1347494400, 
1321142400, 1294876800, 1268438400, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date8 = structure(c(1505260800, 1478995200, 
1452643200, 1426204800, 1399939200, 1189641600, 1163376000, 1137110400, 
1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 1031875200, 1005609600, 979344000, 
952905600, 926553600, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date9 = structure(c(1505347200, 1189641600, 
1163376000, 1137110400, 1110672000, 1084406400, 1058054400, 1031875200, 
1005609600, 979344000, 952905600, 926553600, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Date10 = structure(c(1505433600, 900288000, 
874108800, 847843200, 821491200, 979344000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date11 = structure(c(1505520000, 611020800, 
584755200, 558489600, 532224000, 874108800, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date12 = structure(c(1505606400, 321753600, 
295401600, 269136000, 242956800, 768787200, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date13 = structure(c(1505692800, 32572800, 
6134400, -20131200, -46396800, 663724800, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date14 = structure(c(1505779200, -256694400, 
-282960000, -309398400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this using `tidyverse`.

First, put dates into long format (tidier). Then put the dates in chronological order with `arrange`. Then remove the `NA`.

After grouping by `Patient_ID`, you can calculate differences between dates, and take the minimum difference. Your `diff` column should be minimum difference between dates.

Does this match the expected outcome?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(...1, Patient_ID), names_to = "number", values_to = "date", names_pattern = "Date(\\d+)") %>%
  arrange(Patient_ID, date) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(Patient_ID) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(date))) %>%
  slice_min(diff, with_ties = FALSE)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 25 x 5
# Groups:   Patient_ID [25]
    ...1 Patient_ID number date                 diff
   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  <dttm>              <dbl>
 1     1          1 9      2017-09-14 00:00:00     1
 2     2          2 9      2007-09-13 00:00:00   304
 3     3          3 9      2006-11-13 00:00:00   304
 4     4          4 3      2006-11-13 00:00:00   304
 5     5          5 9      2005-03-13 00:00:00   304
 6     6          6 3      2005-03-13 00:00:00   304
 7     7          7 9      2003-07-13 00:00:00   303
 8     8          8 3      2003-07-13 00:00:00   303
 9     9          9 5      2012-09-13 00:00:00     0
10    10         10 5      2011-11-13 00:00:00     0
11    11         11 5      2011-01-13 00:00:00     0
12    12         12 5      2010-03-13 00:00:00     0
13    13         13 3      1999-05-13 00:00:00   607
14    14         14 1      2008-07-13 00:00:00   608
15    15         15 8      2000-03-13 00:00:00   303
16    16         16 3      1999-05-16 00:00:00     3
17    17         17 4      2001-01-13 00:00:00   607
18    18         18 4      2000-03-13 00:00:00   300
19    19         19 3      1999-05-19 00:00:00     6
20    20         20 3      1999-05-20 00:00:00     6
21    21         21 3      1999-05-21 00:00:00     6
22    22         22 3      1999-05-22 00:00:00     6
23    23         23 4      1999-05-17 00:00:00     4
24    24         24 4      1999-05-18 00:00:00     4
25    25         25 4      1999-05-19 00:00:00     6
```

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks for your answer! I get the Error: Error: object 'slice_min' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: `slice_min` is with the latest version of `dplyr` - what version are you using? you can also try `slice(which.min(diff))`

Comment: Dear Ben, I downloaded the newest version, now it works perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned with efficiency, you can use the outer function. Lets say your dataset is call `d`

```
cols = colnames(d)[-1]  #remove id column
resultNames = outer(cols, cols, paste, sep="_") #column names
result = outer(2:ncol(d), 2:ncol(d), function(x, y) d[,x] - d[,y]) #do pairwise differences, ignoring first column 
colnames(result) <- resultNames
```

Now `result` will have your pairwise differences. I'm not sure if you want to flag all occurrences or the first, but you can use the [which](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which) function.

This isn't the most efficient however as the running time is `O(n^2)`. A more efficient algorithm is [using divide and conquer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/) but you would need to code an implementation of this